# using std::tolower with std::transform

Tags: c++

I would like to understand why fully qualifying with `std::` results in the compilation error below using `std::transform`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower); // does not compile

    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower); // OK
}
```

Error that it cannot deduce unary operator.

```
source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:4:19: error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
    4 |     std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/algorithm:62,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4285:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IIter, class _OIter, class _UnaryOperation> constexpr _OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation)'
 4285 |     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4285:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:4:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_UnaryOperation'
    4 |     std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify, which [one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) of [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) functions in std namespace you want:

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower));
```

Note that you also missing `string` and `cctype` includes.

Comment: Why does ```::tolower``` work?

Comment: @user3882729 because single-character tolower is present in global namespacea as a C relict. Function from `locale` does not.

Answer (score 2):

It is advised not to use `std::tolower()` with standard algorithms, as you need to first cast the input to `unsigned char`.

You could use an anonymous function as follows:

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), 
               [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); }
              );
```

Your code implicitly includes `string` header that probably includes C standard library headers that define basic character handling functions. That is why the version using `::tolower()` compiles.

Comment: I rather guess that the program is implicitly including `<locale>`, so that another version of `toupper` is in the `std` namespace. That seems to have been the cause in the duplicate question.

Comment: Also, `std::tolower` is one of the *non-addressable functions* (because it may be implemented as an intrinsic), so wrapping it in a lambda is double-plus-good, in addition to the `unsigned char`.